# Java Eclipse Helios 2 Release Java SE 7 Support

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7, helios

we finally have migrate into Java SE 7 in out project we been working with

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911
```

for some quite long. i am trying to set everything to get all the Java SE 7 new Stuff i was trying to set the Eclipse Compiler to 7 but surprise the Compiler for Java SE 6 is the last

i was wondering if exists any fix or plugins to get eclipse approval my Java 7 sintax as well their support without install a new eclipse...

please take a look the image[image].

[update]
yes in fact i have to upgrade to `KEPLEER` this raises another question which is differences between `Eclipse Standard 4.3, 198 MB` and `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, 246 MB` does `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, 246 MB` have the latest version of eclipse `KEPLER` sorry by the question i have programming almost entire in `Netbeans.`

Comment: Elipse has several different downloads which are the core product with given sets of added plugins,  you could as well download them afterwards.  If you need to do war files get the EE version, otherwise classic Eclipse will be just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Helios does not support Java 7 syntax.  It is also an over three year old product.  Kepler just came out.  Last year Juno came out.  The year before Indigo came out.  Before THAT Helios came out.

Why can't you upgrade your Eclipse?

Comment: The [Eclipse matrix](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=kepler) shows the differences between Kepler versions.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses its own internal compiler and not javac from the JDK.

Hence you need a version of Eclipse officially supporting Java 7 which Helios doesn't. I would suggest the latest version of Eclipse Juno (4.2) and not the brand new Kepler (4.3) because it has had a year of bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to Juno version http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/