# Can't switch to compiler compliance level 1.8 in Eclipse Helios

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, java-8

I am pretty new to eclipse and programming,Currently i am trying to learn java from a tutorial from [caveofprogramming.com](http://caveofprogramming.com)
When i was trying to follow one tutorial based on switch an error keep disturbing me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class App{

public static void main(String[] args){

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("enter a number");

 String text = input.nextLine();

 switch(text) {

 case "start";

 System.out.println("Machine started");

 break; }  }   }
```

And it gives me an error on the switch command saying:

> cannot switch on a value of type string. only int values or enum constants are permitted

John Purcell at [caveofprogramming.com](http://caveofprogramming.com)  suggested that its because of the compiler compliance level which is currently 1.4 and he said me to switch that to 1.8 but its not available there.1.6 is the last level which i can use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Eclipse Helios 2 Release Java SE 7 Support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618078/java-eclipse-helios-2-release-java-se-7-support)

Comment: @shivam Can i upgrade my eclipse from helios to juno or later versions?

Comment: You should upgrade to at least 4.4 (Luna) from 2014 for full Java 8 support. Might as well update the *current* version, which is 4.6 (Neon), just released last month.

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP yes update it to latest version .. it will work

Comment: @shivam How to update it from helios to later versions?

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP Help-> check for updates

Comment: @shivam Am currently doing that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install the [current Eclipse version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/neonr). Eclipse has a build-in Java compiler. Switching on `String`s was added in Java SE 1.7. Java SE 1.4 is a very old version of Java. It's not a good idea to learn programming using a version of Java which is that old.

Also, as the other answer suggests, install the latest JDK.

Comment: i am currently downloading eclipse neon.but i have helios already.Any problem?

Comment: To install Eclipse you need to simply unpack it's zip archive. So, I do not think you absolutely have to remove Helios before installing Neon. But it probably does not make sense to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is correct in saying that it is because of a compiler compliance level. In order to be able to fix your problem, your compiler must be version 1.7 or 1.8. If you're using an IDE, you'll need to [download a JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) to match up to whichever version you need (would recommend 1.8 as it's not EOL'd). If you're using Maven, you can change your compiler level by using the [Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/).

Comment: Am currently using Helios any way to upgrade directly from Helios to Luna or Neon?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Although I'm not sure why you're choosing to upgrade right now, unless there's a JDK restriction on the compiler, a dry install will work every time.

Comment: Java 8 was released in March 2014. Helios's last maintenance release was in February 2011. Java 8 didn't exist yet. Even Java 7 wouldn't be out for several months. Eclipse uses an internal compiler, so it needs to be updated.